# Way to set items of b-table by parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I'm looking for a clean way to set items of `b-table` by parent component.

```js
<ScrollableComponent ref="scrollTable" class="tableDiv">
   <b-table hover bordered no-border-collapse show-empty :items="This need to be set by ScrollableComponent"></b-table>
</ScrollableComponent>
```

I want to `ScrollableComponent` set items of `b-table`. I've tried something like that in `ScrollableComponent` but this doesn't work:

```js
<div ref="scrollable-div" @scroll.passive="onScroll" @scrollend="onScroll">
   <slot :items="this.items"></slot>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass props to slots is not a good idea because slots (including default slot) from your page are readonly for `ScrollableComponent`.

If you really want it, you can use [Provide / Inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) instead of props.